# Correcting errors and inefficiency when concatenating hundreds of clips with time offsets in FFMPEG

Tags: ffmpeg

I am attempting to automate multicam editing with FFMPEG. Basically there is some number of time-synced videos, typically up to 7. There is also a list of "clips" from the source videos (e.g. Camera 1 from 0-4sec, Camera 2 from 4-5.5sec, Camera 1 from 5.5-8sec). I have tried three methods to render a final video: `overlay` clips, render clips then `concat` them, and `trim`/`concat` to extract clips in one command and I have not had success with any of them.

#### Attempted Method 1: Overlays

The idea here was for each source video to be an input, then create a large filter of overlays to take place each cut/clip at the correct time. The audio is given as the first input and a black screen is given as the second input.

**FFMPEG command:**

```
ffmpeg -y -i audio.flac -f lavfi -i color=c=black:s=1920x1080 \
  -i video1.mp4 -i video2.mp4 -i video3.mp4 -i video4.mp4 -i video5.mp4 \
  -filter_complex_script ffmpeg_filters.txt -map "[edit289]" -map 0:a \
  -vcodec libx264 -c:a copy -t 4629 "output.mp4"
```

**Example `ffmpeg_filters.txt`:**

```
[1:v][2:v]overlay=enable='between(t,0,4.99229)'[edit1];
[edit1][3:v]overlay=enable='between(t,4.99229,10.0078)'[edit2];
[edit2][2:v]overlay=enable='between(t,10.0078,14.0016)'[edit3];
[edit3][5:v]overlay=enable='between(t,14.0016,15.9985)'[edit4];
...
[edit287][2:v]overlay=enable='between(t,4503,4624)'[edit288];
[edit288][4:v]overlay=enable='between(t,4624,4629.99)'[edit289]
```

The issue here is that it renders at something like 0.04x speed. The final video is something like 1-2 hours, so it would take well over 24 hours to render. This seems absurdly slow. Additionally the [documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#overlay-1) specifically says `You can chain together more overlays but you should test the efficiency of such approach.` So perhaps this is not a good way to do it. Is there any way to speed this method up?

#### Attempted Method 2: Render Clips and Concatenate

Since the first method was proving to be far too slow, I attempted to render each clip into its own file named `edit###.mp4` and then concatenate them, but I ran into issues there, as well.

**Rendering clips to files (with no audio):**

```
ffmpeg -y -i video1.mp4 -ss 0 -t 4.99229 -an -c:v libx264 edit000.mp4
ffmpeg -y -i video2.mp4 -ss 4.99229 -t 5.01551 -an -c:v libx264 edit001.mp4
ffmpeg -y -i video1.mp4 -ss 10.0078 -t 3.99383 -an -c:v libx264 edit002.mp4
...
ffmpeg -y -i video3.mp4 -ss 4624 -t 209.001 -an -c:v libx264 edit288.mp4
```

This appears to mostly work, however, some of the resulting files are under 1K and are not valid video files. I believe they may be too short. I can work around that, so I'm not worried about that part.

**Concatenating clips:**

```
ffmpeg -y -i audio.flac -f lavfi -i color=c=black:s=1920x1080 -safe 0 \
  -f concat -i input_clips.txt -filter_complex_script clip_filters.txt \
  -map [0:a] -map "[outv]" -c:v libx264 -t 4833 -c:a aac output_clips.mp4
```

Since the list of input files is so long, I put them into `input_clips.txt`. `clip_filters.txt` contains all the time offsets for each input file.

**`input_clips.txt`**

```
file 'edit000.mp4'
file 'edit001.mp4'
file 'edit002.mp4'
...
file 'edit288.mp4'
```

**`clip_filters.txt`**

```
[2:v]setpts=PTS-STARTPTS+0/TB[v0];
[3:v]setpts=PTS-STARTPTS+4.99229/TB[v1];
[4:v]setpts=PTS-STARTPTS+10.0078/TB[v2];
[5:v]setpts=PTS-STARTPTS+14.0016/TB[v3];
...
[290:v]setpts=PTS-STARTPTS+4624/TB[v288];
[v0][v1][v2][v3]...[v290]concat=n=289:v=1[outv]
```

This call causes an error:

```
...
Input #2, concat, from 'input_clips.txt':
  Duration: N/A, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 4781 kb/s
  Stream #2:0(eng): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuvj420p(pc, bt709, progressive), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 4781 kb/s, 59.94 fps, 59.94 tbr, 60k tbn
    Metadata:
      handler_name    :  GoPro AVC
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
      encoder         : Lavc60.2.100 libx264
      timecode        : 10:20:07:10
  Stream #2:1: Unknown: none
Invalid file index 3 in filtergraph description [2:v]setpts=PTS-STARTPTS+0/TB[v0];
[3:v]setpts=PTS-STARTPTS+4.99229/TB[v1];
[4:v]setpts=PTS-STARTPTS+10.0078/TB[v2];
[5:v]setpts=PTS-STARTPTS+14.0016/TB[v3];
...
```

Is it having problems reading in the 'input_clips.txt' or something? It's not clear to me what is causing the errors. I have tried using full paths, relative paths, no paths (as shown), and using `file file:edit###.mp4` syntax.

#### Attempted Method 3: Trim & Concat

This method will run but is even slower than the `overlay` method above. It is sort of an amalgamation of the two methods above but it uses the `trim` filter instead of `overlay` or rendering.

**FFMPEG command:**

```
ffmpeg -y -i video1.mp4 -i video2.mp4 -i video3.mp4 -i video4.mp4 -i video5.mp4 \
  -filter_complex_script ffmpeg_filters.txt -map "[edit289]" -map "[outv]" \
  -vcodec libx264 -an -t 4629 "output.mp4"
```

**Example `ffmpeg_filters.txt`:**

```
[0:v]trim=0:4.99229,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[v0];
[5:v]trim=4.99229:10.0078,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[v1];
[0:v]trim=10.0078:14.0016,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[v2];
[5:v]trim=14.0016:15.9985,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[v3];
...
[2:v]trim=4624:4833,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[v288];
[v0][v1][v2][v3]...[v288]concat=n=289:v=1[outv]
```

#### Bottom Line

- Since none of these methods have been too successful, is there a better way to go about rendering these time-offset cuts to a single video?
- Is there any way to speed up the `overlay` render?
- What is causing the error in the `concat` method?
- Any idea why `trim` is slower than `overlay` in this implementation?

Comment: method 2 is wrong, try this: `ffmpeg -safe 0 -f concat -i input_clips.txt -c copy output_clips.mp4`